# How to use vbs to open a specific sheet within an excel document via windows shortcut

Tags: excel, windows, vbscript, shortcut-file

I could use some help. I found an archived post that shows how to open a excel file and go directly to a specified sheet via a Windows Shortcut. I have tried this code and I can modify it to open excel and open a specific document, but its not switching to a specific tab. Any help would be appreciated.

"this is passed as a command line parameter to the script so that you can change it with each shortcut that you have.

```
ExcelB.vbs:
' Starts Excel, opens a file and passes a parameter to Excel via environment variable
' Syntax: ExcelB.vbs FileName Parameter

'Write to environment variable - from the 2nd command line parameter: Item(1)
'Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("ExcelParam") = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

'open Excel with the filename passed from the 1st command line parameter: Item(0)
Set objShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0))

In Excel, create VBA code to read the environment variable and goto the desired cell
Private Sub Auto_Open()
Dim sParam As String,
Dim sCell As String
Dim sCellR1 As String

sParam = Environ("ExcelParam")

If Left(sParam, 1) = "#" Then
sCell = Mid(sParam, 2, 200)
sCellR1 = Application.ConvertFormula(sCell, xlA1, xlR1C1)
Application.Goto sCellR1
End If
End Sub
```

I've designated a '#' symbol as a trigger for "goto a cell", so that other commands could be added if required
This is also in keeping with MS standards (if you create a hyperlink to a cell in Excel and then examine the hyperlink you will see that it uses this same format)

Lastly, you'll need to create Shortcuts in Windows File Explorer with the following format for the 'Target' setting in the shortcut:
C:\ExecelB.vbs C:\testfile.xlsm #Sheet2!A3

And there you have it - Windows Shortcuts which will open an Excel spreadsheet to a specific sheet/cell"

I follow these steps but its still not working as this person says it works.

The error Code that i get:

```
Line: 7 
Char: 1 
Error: Object required: 'objShell' 
Code: 800A01A8
```

If anyone has an idea as to what I have done wrong I would be forever in your debt!

Update:

I was able to get rid of the error code by changing:

```
'Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("ExcelParam") = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

changed to:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("ExcelParam") = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

So far I am now able to open the excel document, but am not able to call the specific sheet from that document.

Edit:
I have found my root problem I believe. In the original Code:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
```

I changed to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

I ran the vba manually and it executed properly. So i googled how to make vba run at open and I had to make that small change for it to work.

Thanks For all that helped me brainstorm

Comment: For `Goto` the documentation does say "If you specify a range on a sheet that's not on top, Microsoft Excel will switch to that sheet before selecting."

Comment: What about `Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` ? (Replace the sheet name)

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a very helpful problem description.

Comment: @GeertBellekens The error code i receive shows:

Line: 7
Char: 1
Error: Object required: 'objShell'
Code: 800A01A8

Comment: @Anders I replaced sheet name in the windows shortcut with the Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate and the error code above is the same

Comment: In your vbs file you are using objShell before creating it.

Comment: @Anders I deleted the " ' " at the beginning of "Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")"

This edit no longer returns an error, which is great, however the document still does nothing after opening. According to that persons post, Excel should read from the Shortcut and go to the specific cell specified.

Comment: And `...Activate` also fails?

Comment: @Anders To be quite honest with you, I am not sure that i am putting that in the correct location. I am very new to VB as this came up as a possible solution when I searched google. I placed the Activate command at the end of the windows shortcut...Is that the correct location? If so, When I placed that there, it did not do anything, it opened the document to the last sheet that was opened previously.

Comment: No, put it after Application.Goto in VBA. (I don't even have Office, I can't really help)

Comment: @Anders I understand now what you were trying to do, I think, lol. I had used:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select

Range(“A1”).Select

End Sub 

which took me to the sheet i needed to open to, however, my document has become over 300 sheets now. The idea was to open a specific sheet from a windows shortcut. So i can recall that sheet without actually editing the macro each time the document is opened. I would only have to change the windows shortcut.

Comment: You can use the same `Environ` trick to specify the sheet but the activation line needs to be in VBA...

Comment: Don't post the error in a comment, but update your question

Comment: @Anders I tried adding the activation to the VBA in excel to no avail. I have tried changing the sheet name to the actual sheet to see if it would change that way and it does not.